# I have had enough of eating burgers

Tags: grammar

> I have had enough of eating burgers.

Can we say that if I eat too much burger continuosly through the day and don't want to eat it anymore?

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with your version, but some of the ones suggested below sound more natural to my ear.

Comment: "I have had enough of eating burgers" to me would suggest a relatively permanent situation. Not just "I don't want any more burgers today" but more like "I don't want any more burgers for a long time and maybe forever."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler to say:

"I have eaten enough burgers today."

Comment: I don't think this really convey's the same meaning.  This statement implies that you had a quota to fill whereas the original one shows that you no longer like the food.

Answer (score 7):

All of these are acceptable as well as some I'm sure I missed:

> I ate enough burgers.
>
> I have eaten enough burgers.
>
> I have had enough burgers.
>
> I've eaten plenty of burgers. I don't want anymore.
>
> I've had my fill of burgers.

Comment: "I've eaten plenty of burgers" doesn't say that you don't want to eat any more, in either British or American English. For example, it would be a perfectly good answer to the question, "Have you ever eaten a burger?"

Comment: @meer2kat My personal favorite after eating too many burgers is: "Blurrrghhhh..." while melting in my chair and making weak flailing motions. It tends to get the point across - though not exactly the best English.

Comment: Satisfied now.? @David

Comment: Hahahah exactly @Alex Mine would be "Stahhhhhpppp!!!" but I don't think that's in the dictionary ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

> "I have eaten my fill of burgers today."

Answer (score 3):

As other people have indicated, there are several different ways this sort of thing can be said, but it's worth noting that some of them can have slightly different implications or impressions on the listener.

"I've had enough of (something)" generally means that you've experienced so much of something that even thinking about it brings up bad feelings for you now.  For example:

> I've had enough of eating burgers.  I don't want to eat another one as
>   long as I live!

On the other hand, saying something like "I've eaten enough burgers" or "I've had enough burgers" is a less strong statement, and might just mean that you're satisfied with the amount you've eaten and don't feel a need to eat more right now:

> I've eaten enough burgers recently.  I think I'll have something else for
>   dinner.

or

> I've had enough burgers today, but if you really want to go to the
>   burger place, I suppose I could eat another one.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that "had enough" is an idiom for expressing **asperity** and a kind of displeasure tinged with strong irritation, and cannot be used without (at least risking) sounding very angry.  I would expect, unless tone of voice and context assured otherwise, that someone who had _had enough_ of eating burgers was right pissed off about how many burgers they had had to eat -- like a high school student protesting the unhealthy offerings in their school's cafeteria.

Answer (score 2):

Saying you already ate a food today is a common way of saying you don't want to eat any more.

> I already ate burgers today.

People often use this construction with yesterday as well. The meaning is the same, since the speaker ate burgers yesterday the listener knows they probably don't want any today either. It is too soon to eat the same food again.

> I had burgers yesterday.

The construction you used "I have had enough of eating burgers." is correct, but has a different meaning! That sentnece means that you ate burgers so often (maybe every day for a year) and now you can't eat any more. They don't taste good to you anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say **I am fed up with burgers for today**

Comment: I think "fed up" describes a longer-term situation than just today. It's equivalent to "I'm bored of burgers", which doesn't make it sound like burgers will be exciting tomorrow, either.

Comment: @DavidRicherby On the other hand, it might be used as a bad pun (not that I'm encouraging new English users to use bad puns!).